# How to authenticate using the Javascript-API.js

Tags: orientdb

How do I authenticate using the `orientdb-api.js` in the browser on OrientDB 2.0.07. I can open a connection using orientServer.open(username, password) and I get a nice DB object back, but subsequent calls I do return a `401 Unauthorized` error.